# invoking server validation on client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've multiple `Ajax.BeginForm` with different sort of data annotations that are applied on the server already and hence it works as expected. Now I want to submit all these ajax forms from a different ajax form using `jqueryform.submit();` I could manage to post the form but whenever i try  `$("#form1").validate();` i thought i should be reinforce my server validations along with the errors but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Just want to know is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve.

i tried to keep it simple... let me explain my situation. I've multiple tabs view for a screen i.e. project view with every tab having separate Ajax.BeginForm as an embedded view and on server side there I've custom conditional validator attribute applied to my Models let say CR which operates or basically gets activated for a given project status only e.g approved and otherwise default validations are enough there i also validate list of checkbox n radiobuttons business rules. For normal business scenario every tab view i.e. Ajax.BeginForm works separately with default or in other words without my custom validations there is a such requirement where I've to submit all of these forms to the server depending on the project status I need to update my client side validations to CR somehow which is not the case because server rendered client validations on the basis of default attributes or without customized CR validation. So once my forms are submitted to the server I can see the model states as IsValid to false mainly because CR attribute is fired... but problem is my whole use case is broken by doing so. I just want to invoke CR validation on the client before posting/submitting my forms. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Everything is possible with a `will` if you try..:)

Comment: that's motivational enough :)

Comment: I meant to say you have not tried anything.Please show your efforts..:P

Comment: elaborated my effort for you.